# Is setting function variables the same as using an object literal

Tags: javascript, json

In terms of performance and the data structure created, is:

```
function coords(xpos, ypos, zpos){
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.zpos = zpos;
    return this;
}
var coordinates = coords(0, 0, 0); // notice I am not calling new
```

The same as:

```
function coords(xpos, ypos, zpos){
    return {
        xpos : xpos,
        ypos : ypos,
        zpos : zpos, 
    };
}
var coordinates = coords(0, 0, 0);
```

Is there are more performant way of generating the `coordinates` assuming I have a lot of them.

Comment: Did you mean `this.xpos = xpos;...` and `var coordinates = new coords(0, 0, 0);`?  If not then these two functions do very different things.

Comment: in this case the fastest way would be to no use a function at all, e.g. `var coordinates = { xpos: 0, ypos: 0, zpos: 0 };` Testing the speed of both types of object creation would require a benchmark, but my guess is that the difference won't the that much different, because both create an object and both get called via one function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first approach for creating an object you have to use

`var coordinates = new coords(0, 0, 0);` and in javascript using `new` is expensive. In the second approach executing the function will return you a coordinate object.

I prefer the second approach though it doesn't make much difference in modern browsers.

here is a simple benchmark http://jsperf.com/objecr-vs-fn-perf-test

in Firefox 7 the first approach is ~75% slower than second and in chrome 17 it si ~30% slower

Answer (score 3):

1. The second example uses an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Object_literals), not [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSON).
2. In terms of semantics: **the two are not semantically equivalent.** Even if you change the `+`s to `=`s in the first example, `coordinates` is `undefined` because you didn't use `new` and `coords` does not return anything.
3. In terms of performance: this is the micro-est of micro-optimizations. Stop thinking about it and move on to solving real problems.
4. If you still care about the performance difference (**you shouldn't**) write a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) benchmark.

---

As [SJFrK commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722682/is-setting-function-variables-the-same-as-using-an-object-literal/9722735#comment12361219_9722682),

> the fastest way would be to no use a function at all, e.g.
>
> ```
> var coordinates = { xpos: 0, ypos: 0, zpos: 0 };
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet should look like this:

```
function coords(xpos, ypos, zpos) {
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.zpos = zpos;
}

var coordinates = new coords(0, 0, 0);
```

That said, your choice will depend on what you want to do with the results (do you want to have an object literal or an object with a prototype you can define), but the performance will be pretty much the same for any reasonable use.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `coordinates` is undefined.  The function isn't returning anything.  You need to use `new` in the first example in order for it to be the same as the second example.  (Also you have a typo, `+` should be `=`)

```
function coords(xpos, ypos, zpos){
    this.xpos = xpos;
    this.ypos = ypos;
    this.zpos = zpos;
}
var coordinates = new coords(0, 0, 0);
```

In your second example, you're not using JSON.  You're just using obect literals.  JSON is a method of representing objects/arrays as strings.

As for performance, the second one would (probably) be faster, but that's not something you should worry about.